# Group multiple rows containing index and create list of custom objects for each index

Tags: c#, string, linq, parsing

I have got a List of strings (read from a file) in this order and format and need to convert into List of class.

```
1.0.1.0.1, Type: DateTime, Value: 06/03/2013 11:06:10
1.0.1.0.2, Type: DateTime, Value: 06/03/2014 11:06:10
1.0.1.0.3, Type: DateTime, Value: 06/03/2015 11:06:10
1.0.1.0.4, Type: DateTime, Value: 06/03/2016 11:06:10
1.0.1.0.5, Type: DateTime, Value: 06/03/2017 11:06:10
1.0.1.1.1, Type: Integer, Value: 1
1.0.1.1.2, Type: Integer, Value: 2
1.0.1.1.3, Type: Integer, Value: 3
1.0.0.1.4, Type: Integer, Value: 4
1.0.1.1.5, Type: Integer, Value: 5
1.0.1.2.1, Type: String, Value: Hello
1.0.1.2.2, Type: String, Value: Hello1
1.0.1.2.3, Type: String, Value: Hello2
1.0.1.2.4, Type: String, Value: Hello3
1.0.1.2.5, Type: String, Value: Hello4
```

Here is my class

```
public class MyData
{
    public DateTime DateTime {get;set;}
    public int Index {get;set;}
    public string Value {get;set;}
}
```

Now What I wanted is to convert it into a list of C# class

Something like this...

```
List<MyData> myDataList  = new List<MyData>();

MyData data1 = new MyData();
data1.DateTime = "06/03/2013 11:06:10";
data1.Index = 1;
data1.Value = "Hello";
myDataList.Add(data1);

MyData data2 = new MyData();
data2.DateTime = "06/03/2014 11:06:10";
data2.Index = 2;
data2.Value = "Hello1";
myDataList.Add(data2);

and so on..
```

This is what I have tried so far.

```
 List<List<string>> allLists = lines
        .Select(str => new { str, token = str.Split('.') })
        .Where(x => x.token.Length >= 4)
        .GroupBy(x => string.Concat(x.token.Take(4)))
        .Select(g => g.Select(x => x.str).ToList())
        .ToList();
```

Do I really need to iterate or can I modify My LINQ to get me desired output ?
Here is my iteration.

```
    foreach (var list in allLists)
    {
          MyData data = new MyData();
          var splittedstring = list[0].Split(',').ToList();
          if (splittedstring.Count == 3)
          {
               var valueData = splittedstring [2];
               var indexof = valueData.IndexOf(':');
               var value = valueData.Substring(indexof + 1);
               // But Over here, how will get DateTime and Index ?
               data.Value = value;
          }
    }
```

Comment: is `1.0.1.1.0, Type: Integer, Value: 1` meant to be `1.0.1.1.1, Type: Integer, Value: 1`?

Comment: @MattBeldon, yes it should be, Sorry its a Typo. I will correct it

Comment: @MattBeldon What difference would that make to solve this at all?

Comment: I see no problem with a loop if it is easier to understand than a chain of linq expressions.

Comment: Ya i also use loop, i gona give you answer from my own class files xD

Comment: "Do I need to iterate..."? Sure, if you want to *handle* every element, you have to *iterate* them. In fact any linq-solution will do the exact same, however it hides this from you.

Comment: @oliver, I am not sure how will construct my class object from 1.0.1.0.1, 1.0.1.1.1, 1.0.1.2.1 while doing a loop.

Comment: Is that newline right? i guess you should split things and do it

Comment: So what do these numbers mean? From what I can figure out, the last one is the item index, and the one before that is the property number? Does the rest bear any significance?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto You could use that value to group the data if they all match

Comment: @Agent_Orange, yeah that's a newline at the end.

Comment: @Nyerguds, the first part of those numbers don't have significance, infact I was trying to group by the last item index only.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution, using Regex. It could be improved by providing a conditional regex match based on the matched type named group(string), but I think the concept is clearer this way, and the regex easier to work with. As it stands, the date format is not validated to be as OP wrote them, they are **assumed** to be as OP wrote them.

This solution is tolerant to some extra spaces and parameters containing commas, but intolerant to inexact matches, i.e. extra fields added or removed in the rows in the future, etc.

The idea is to first parse the rows to a more "friendly" format, and then group the friendly format by index and return the MyData rows by iterating each group (by index).

[image: Sample]

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"^(?<fieldName>(\d\.)+(?<index>\d*)), *Type: *(?<dataType>.*), *Value: (?<dataValue>.*)$");

public class MyData
{
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
    public int Index { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

class LogRow
{
    public int Index { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

//In a parser I would rather not be too defensive, I let exceptions bubble up
IEnumerable<LogRow> ParseRows(IEnumerable<string> lines)
{
    foreach (var line in lines)
    {
       var match = r.Matches(line).AsQueryable().Cast<Match>().Single();
       yield return new LogRow()
       {
          Index = int.Parse(match.Groups["index"].Value),
          Type = match.Groups["dataType"].Value,
              Value = match.Groups["dataValue"].Value
       };
   }
}

IEnumerable<MyData> RowsToData(IEnumerable<LogRow> rows)
{
   var byIndex = rows.GroupBy(b => b.Index).OrderBy(b=> b.Key);
   //assume that rows exist for all MyData fields for a given index
   foreach (var group in byIndex)
   {
      var rawRow = group.ToDictionary(g => g.Type, g => g);
      var date = DateTime.ParseExact(rawRow["DateTime"].Value, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

      yield return new MyData() { Index = group.Key, DateTime = date, Value = rawRow["String"].Value };
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
var myDataList = RowsToData(ParseRows(File.ReadAllLines("input.txt"))).ToList();
```

Comment: each line only gives a single property though. And that doesn't match the given class at all.

Comment: @Nyerguds OP was having trouble identifying and putting data where it needs to be. Does this answer address this concern?

Comment: @AlexC, 
var match = r.Matches.SingleOrDefault(); Line Gives an Error saying that error CS0119: 'Regex.Matches(string, string)' is a method, which is not valid in the given context

Comment: The offered `MyData` class has a `DateTime`, `Index` and `Value`. You return a `version`, `dataType` and `dataValue`. These don't match at all. It's only enough to fill up one single property of the `MyData` class.

Comment: @Pankaj see updated answer, that should work, I think. Working on mobile here, hard  :)

Comment: @Nyerguds what about the rows that have integers and strings in the Value: field? Class design is a separate topic in my opinion. The class should be probably modeled as ValueHolder<Type>. The constructor is not relevant here, for illustrating the concept. Also, all the properties are extracted with that one single regex!!!!

Comment: Each line is only one class property... you need three for each object.

Comment: @Nyerguds new MyData(match["version"], match["dataType"], match["dataValue"]) how is that one property ????? You should read OP's question again, he wants those values in a list. What are you talking about?

Comment: That is the datatype and datavalue of _one property._ Look at your returned data, and at the MyData class in the question. They don't match at all.

Comment: @Nyerguds Here is the final clarification: The sample I provided captures 4 groups: first "version" (the first number group in OP's sample), the next group(unnamed) is the index if OP wants to use it, the third "dataType" which is "DateTime" or "Integer" or "String", and the final one is the string representation of the value desired in the MyData class. Then I said that at that point you can instantiate the class, so I used a fictional constructor with 3 parameters of the 4 captured. If THIS is that much of a problem to you, suggest an edit or downvote my answer, I am done here! Screenshot

Comment: @Nyerguds On further thinking, I think you might be unfamiliar with the yield keyword

Comment: I know what "yield" means. It means you return a new `MyData` object for each found property, while each such object requires three different properties (a DateTime, Integer _and_ String) to be complete. Your fictional constructor doesn't even match the properties inside the class.

Comment: @Nyerguds There are 4 different groups in the regex. A single regex returns 4 values as outlined in my previous comment. That regex validates and parses one whole line. I don't get what you don't get. Also, a constructor signature is hardly a concern for illustrating the concept of parsing ....

Answer (score 1):

First, fix your `GroupBy`: `string.Concat(x.token.Take(4))` may create uncertainties when dot-separated numbers are ambiguous. For example, `1.23.4.5` and `12.3.4.5` would both produce `"12345"` string. Use `string.Join` with some non-numeric separator instead:

```
.GroupBy(x => string.Join("|", x.token.Take(4)))
```

Now for the main part of your question an easy fix would be to add a static method that parses the list of three strings, and use it in your LINQ query:

```
List<MyData> dataList = lines
    .Select(str => new { str, token = str.Split('.') })
    .Where(x => x.token.Length >= 4)
    .GroupBy(x => string.Concat(x.token.Take(4)))
    .Select(g => g.Select(x => x.str).ToList())
    .Where(list => list.Count == 3)
    .Select(MyDataFromList)
    .ToList();
...
private static MyData MyDataFromList(List<string> parts) {
    if (parts.Count != 3) {
        throw new ArgumentException(nameof(parts));
    }
    var byType = parts
        .Select(ToTypeAndValue)
        .ToDictionary(t => t.Item1, t => t.Item2)
    return new MyData {
        DateTime = DateTime.Parse(byType["DateTime"])
    ,   Index = int.Parse(byType["Integer"])
    ,   Value = byType["String"]
    };
}
private static Tuple<string,string> ToTypeAndValue(string s) {
    var tokens = s.Split(',');
    if (tokens.Length != 3) return null;
    var typeParts = tokens[1].Split(':');
    if (typeParts.Length != 2 || typeParts[0] != "Type") return null;
    var valueParts = tokens[2].Split(':');
    if (valueParts.Length != 2 || valueParts[0] != "Value") return null;
    return Tuple.Create(typeParts[1].Trim(), typeParts[2].Trim());
}
```

Note that the above code makes an assumption that the three types are unique (hence the use of `Dictionary<string,string>`). This is required, because the structure of your data provides no other way to tie the values to fields of `MyData`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using regular expressions. It would look like:

```
public List<MyData> GetData(string str){
    var regexDate = new Regex(@"\d\.\d\.\d\.\d\.(?<id>\d).*DateTime.*Value:\s*(?<val>.*)");
    var regexInteger = new Regex(@"\d\.\d\.\d\.\d\.(?<id>\d).*Integer.*Value:\s*(?<val>.*)");
    var regexString = new Regex(@"\d\.\d\.\d\.\d\.(?<id>\d).*String.*Value:\s*(?<val>.*)");

    var dict = new Dictionary<int, MyData>();

    foreach (Match myMatch in regexDate.Matches(str))
    {
        if (!myMatch.Success) continue;

        var index = int.Parse(myMatch.Groups["id"].Value);
        dict[index] = new MyData()
        {
            Index = index,
            DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(myMatch.Groups["val"].Value, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
        };
    }

    foreach (Match myMatch in regexInteger.Matches(str))
    {
        if (!myMatch.Success) continue;

        var index = int.Parse(myMatch.Groups["id"].Value);
        dict[index].Index = Int32.Parse(myMatch.Groups["val"].Value);
    }

    foreach (Match myMatch in regexString.Matches(str))
    {
        if (!myMatch.Success) continue;

        var index = int.Parse(myMatch.Groups["id"].Value);
        dict[index].Value = myMatch.Groups["val"].Value;
    }

    return dict.Values
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd just go for the manual approach... and since that list of integers at the start contains indices for the objects and for the properties, it'd only be logical to use these instead of the type strings.

Using a `Dictionary`, you can use that object-index to make a new object at the moment you find any of its properties, and store it using that index. And whenever you encounter another properties for the same index, you retrieve the object and fill in that property on it.

```
public static List<MyData> getObj(String[] lines)
{
    Dictionary<Int32, MyData> myDataDict = new Dictionary<Int32, MyData>();
    const String valueStart = "Value: ";
    foreach (String line in lines)
    {
        String[] split = line.Split(',');
        // Too many fail cases; I just ignore any line that stops matching at any point.
        if (split.Length < 3)
            continue;
        String[] numData = split[0].Trim().Split('.');
        if (numData.Length < 5)
           continue;
        // Using the 4th number as property identifier. Could also use the
        // type string, but switch/case on a numeric value is more elegant.
        Int32 prop;
        if (!Int32.TryParse(numData[3], out prop))
           continue;
        // Object index, used to reference the objects in the Dictionary.
        Int32 index;
        if (!Int32.TryParse(numData[4], out index))
           continue;
        String typeDef = split[1].Trim();
        String val = split[2].TrimStart();
        if (!val.StartsWith(valueStart))
           continue;
        val = val.Substring(valueStart.Length);
        MyData data;
        if (myDataDict.ContainsKey(index))
            data = myDataDict[index];
        else
        {
            data = new MyData();
            myDataDict.Add(index, data);
        }
        switch (prop)
        {
            case 0:
                if (!"Type: DateTime".Equals(typeDef))
                    continue;
                DateTime dateVal;
                // Don't know if this date format is correct; adapt as needed.
                if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(val, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out dateVal))
                    continue;
                data.DateTime = dateVal;
                break;
            case 1:
                if (!"Type: Integer".Equals(typeDef))
                    continue;
                Int32 numVal;
                if (!Int32.TryParse(val, out numVal))
                    continue;
                data.Index = numVal;
                break;
            case 2:
                if (!"Type: String".Equals(typeDef)) continue;
                data.Value = val;
                break;
        }
    }
    return new List<MyData>(myDataDict.Values);
}
```

Comment: Nice clean approach. One method to rule them all! I would like to see you write unnit tests for this =))

Comment: Unit testing is hardly a concern when outlining a method to get those objects filled. And, did you seriously just downvote me out of spite? Wow, man. Low.

Comment: I did not downvote you, I left a comment... I was just admiring the readability of the code!

Comment: Oh, I see what you meant now in your comments. You were right! Even though I find this way of storing rows bonkers, I get your point. I will delete my answer for now, and come back with a solution that fullyaddresses the question. By the way, good job on understanding a madman's dream .:)

Comment: yeah, the sane way to handle this would be in a two-step process, first parsing all the props, and then combining them per index... but I worked around that by using that `Dictionary`.

Comment: I don't think any answer will be 100% for OP's solution... SO is not code outsourcing as far as I know.... About the Dictionary, that is not the only way to work around it. see my updated answer.... Crappy way to hold data and very fragile code whatever we would write. That's why I mentioned unit testing. Developers have this tendency to try catch everything and then you get "my data does not display in winforms" question follow-ups :)

Comment: Also, sorry for the anger, rough day here :)

Comment: No prob... but you can see how, after that, I'd mistake your initial comment for sarcasm :-\

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution to your problem. I have already tested it, you can test it to here: [Raw To Custom List](http://rextester.com/HEMIR44731)

```
string text = rawData;

//Raw Data Is the exact data you read from textfile without modifications.
List<MyData> myDataList  = new List<MyData>();

string[] eElco = text.Split( new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None );
var tmem = eElco.Count();
var eachP = tmem / 3;

List<string> unDefVal = new List<string>();
foreach (string rw in eElco)
{
    String onlyVal = rw.Split(new[] { "Value: " } , StringSplitOptions.None)[1];
    unDefVal.Add(onlyVal);
}

for (int i = 0; i < eachP; i++)
{
    int ind = Int32.Parse(unDefVal[i + eachP]);
    DateTime oDate = DateTime.ParseExact(unDefVal[i], "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    MyData data1 = new MyData();
    data1.DateTime = oDate;
    data1.Index = ind;
    data1.Value = unDefVal[i + eachP + eachP];
    myDataList.Add(data1);

    Console.WriteLine("Val1 = {0}, Val2 = {1}, Val3 = {2}",
    myDataList[i].Index,
    myDataList[i].DateTime,
    myDataList[i].Value);    
}
```